# Jquery templates and data-for

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am building a table of repeating information for my site, and control, showing and hiding individual sections using an icon. Now, for hard coded instances, I can use the following:

```
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 dropdown-user" data-for=".user">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down text-muted"></i>
   </div>
```

Which is linked to the following div:

```
 <div class="row user-infos user">
   .....table content
 </div>
```

So, my question is, how can i specify a unique data-for attribute for each iteration. Something like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 dropdown-user" data-for=".user1">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down text-muted"></i>
</div>
<div class="row user-infos user1">
   .....table content for user 1
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 dropdown-user" data-for=".user2">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down text-muted"></i>
</div>
<div class="row user-infos user2">
   .....table content for user 2
</div>
........
```

All the data is populated using Jquery templates, so my variables are in the format of:
    ${somevalue};

***EDIT***

Should note that i am iterating over my data set via Ajax success:

```
  $.each(msg.d, function(index, item) {
      $('#usertmpl').tmpl(item).appendTo('#results');
  });
```

and my template:

```
<script id="usertmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <table class="table table-user-information" id="approveScroll" style="height: 100px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="approved by"></i> ${UserName}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span id="approvedDate"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="approved date"></i> ${parseJsonDate(EnteredDate)}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span id="approveComment"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="comment"></i> ${Comment}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>
```

this all gets appended to a containing DIV.

***EDIT***[image]

Comment: You can define counter before iteration, and concat it with class `.user`

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL, i know i need a counter, but i'm struggling on how to pass in a paraeter into the <div data-for= i've tried this:

data-for="${value} but it doesn't work

Comment: you can see my answer. Use `${$index}` for unique key on iteration. On demo, inspect element and see class names are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design unique key by using `${$index}` like;

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="jqTpl">
    {{each data.users}}
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 dropdown-user" data-for=".user${$index +1}">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down text-muted"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="row user-infos user${$index +1}">
         User${$index +1}
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
 var json={
     "data": {
         "users": [
             3,
             2,
             1
         ]
     }
 }   
</script>
```

For show this template in page;

`$( "#jqTpl" ).tmpl( json ).appendTo( "body" )`

You can see working demo here: **http://jsfiddle.net/huseyinbabal/eQbvT/2/**

On demo, inspect element and see class names are unique

**Update:** For tooltip fix add following;

```
$('i[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    animated: 'fade',
    placement: 'bottom',
});
```

Here is working demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/huseyinbabal/eQbvT/1/**

Comment: I think we are using them in a slightly different approach. see mark up addition above.

Comment: Ok, correction, that worked the same. However, none of the data-for, or tooltips worked. there not firing

Comment: No errors, i've added screen shot of output, the html looks fine, jsut not doing anything, neither are any of the buttons, unless i add onclick and call a function.

Comment: Must be something else interfering with this, as they are still not showing. I see how your's works, but mine isn't - oh the joys :-)

Comment: In your screenshot, there is no data toggle tooltip. Are you sure, you have added tooltip to that elements?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49217/discussion-between-csharpnewbee-and-huseyin-babal)